# Login loop with Xorg on Ubuntu 17.10, but Wayland works

Tags: xorg, login, wayland

I am using Ubuntu 17.10. I was using xorg session because some screen monitoring applications were not working in Wayland (e.g. Timedoctor taking blank screenshots).

Yesterday when I turned my computer on to log in (in Xorg), after I entered my password a black animation type screen appeared and the login screen came back. I tried again but it wasn't working.

On the default session I have no problem logging in. I have also tried to installed Unity, but with that I have the same problem as with Xorg.

I want to use Xorg session. How can I fix the login loop?

Comment: Xorg is not a desktop environment, Unity is not a graphics server...